# CMA Memory Reserve Not Working

Tags: linux, memory, debian

I'm a Debian 12 user.
I compiled Linux kernel 6.5.3 with CMA support enabled.
However, even passing the size of the CMA reservation through Grub `(CMA=4G)`, I cannot reserve memory for the `CMA`.

The system logs say:

> Unknown kernel command line parameters "splash BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.3.mmn.cma.nosuspend.v3 CMA=4G", will be passed to user space.

What can this be?
How to solve it?